# JQuery Tag Help Me

Tags: jquery

I don't understand one tag in cript after:

```
if (!$.browser.opera) {
    // select element styling
    $('select.select').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
        $(this)
            .css({'z-index':10,'opacity':0,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
            .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
            .live('change', function(){
                val = $('option:selected',this).text();
                $(this).next().text(val);
            });

        $(this).nextAll().remove();
    });
};
```

Tag "select.select" in above script.
I bold it;
What it mean?
Thanks!

Comment: It means `<select>` tag with `class="select"` attribute.

Comment: dropdown with class ``select``

Answer (score 3):

This mean `select` tags with `select` class

```
<select class="select"></select>
```

[About selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select.select').each(function() { // ** was added for bolding purpose
```

If that is the code, then it means the `select` element with the class name `select.

This jQuery code would select the select Element from the Document which has select className too. Then it would execute the code specified in the `function ()` call.

Something like this

```
<select class="select">
  <!-- options here -->
</select>
```

The above is the example sample for the select element that would be selected.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi he added ** to make it bold.

Comment: I write wrong, I have just update a question. Can you help me?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi He is trying to bold it out! :) with inbuilt SO editor :)

Comment: @DonaldNguyễn, I have editted my answer too :) I understood your problem in the very first stage. That asterisk was to bold it, whereas in SO codeblock that doesn't work. So, have the answer now :) It has the explaination too...Hope you get my point brother :0

Answer (score 1):

`$('select.select')`

means that select all the select elements on the page with the class name "select"

Answer (score 0):

The code wasn't readable from your question, but the source said

```
select.select
```

This is a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) selecting ALL the `select` elements with class name `select`.

The `.each` behind it executes the action specified after it on every occurrence within the results.

Answer (score 0):

This selector:

```
$('select.select')
```

says:

get the select element which have the class name `.select`.

`.` is class notation in jQuery.
`#` is id notation in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`$('select.select').each()` is assuming that there are multiple `<select>` tags with a class named `select` like this:

```
<SELECT class="select" title="select1"  >
    ....
</SLECT>

<SELECT class="select" title="select2" >
    ....
</SLECT>

<SELECT class="select" title="select3" >
    ....
</SLECT>
```

Hope this helps.